# Javascript doesn't work in column

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm using this http://www.proglogic.com/code/javascript/calculator/bmi.php Body Mass Index calculator javascript for my wordpress website.

It works in wordpress sidebar, works also on wordpress simple page.

But doesn't work on main page http://prc.ge/?lang=en between the columns

```
[column width="1/4" title="" title_type="single" animation="none" implicit="true"][/column]
```

Any solution?!

Comment: "doesn't work" is a bit unprecise.

Comment: Doesn't calculate when you enter your data and click the calculate button. Nothing happens.

Comment: Do you get an error or something? It's hard to read your page ;)

Comment: Ok, I'll translate right now

Comment: Done. Now here http://prc.ge/bariatgeo/ you can test this calculator. It works in sidebar but doesn't work in column on main page. Nothing happens when you enter your data and click the calculate button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at the code of your pages, then will you see that you do not have any javascript call in the page that is returning no information.

If you have Firebug installed on your Firefox, then can you see that.
The line in your official website is:

```
<input type="button" value="ინდექსის გამოთვლა">
```

where in your wordpress site it is:

```
<input type="button" onclick="calculateBmi()" value="Calculate">
```

Adding the onclick-event will help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. This calculator works in sidebar very well, but doesn't work in columns on main page. So, I don't understand your comment. If there is any mistake, it must be for both pages. For sidebar and for main page, isn't it?